# Connection timeouts trying to reach Nginx

Tags: nginx, tcp

I'm getting intermittent connection timeouts from an external client trying to reach an Nginx instance behind a firewall doing DNAT. Most requests succeed fine, but some timeout.

The Nginx box has very little load, so its CPU is not maxed out. A tcpdump on the machine shows the client packets reaching the machine, including several TCP retransmissions, but never any response from the Nginx box.

Here are the config bits relevant to connections. At one recent check with `netstat -peanut`, the box had about 500 connections in various states, which shouldn't be enough to cause problems.

```
events {
    worker_connections                  20000;
}
worker_processes                        16;
worker_rlimit_nofile                    40100;
```

What do I check next?

Comment: Is there an environment in which you can replicate the issue where you can safely turn the firewall off to observe if there's any difference?

Comment: Unfortunately no. :-(